# My wordpress site goes down too often and it is very slow with Basic theme from themify

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

My site goes down too often and I always get this error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string
>   supplied as input in
>   /nfs/c10/h03/mnt/142716/domains/mysite.com/html/wp-content/themes/basic/themify/themify-builder/includes/libraries/parsers.php
>   on line 71

and I have no idea what it means, and my site is very slow while using Basic theme, if I change to an other theme I run fast, it go down even in the backend here is the link to the theme site http://themify.me/themes/basic

Please help

Comment: What is in parsers.php on line 71? Did you take a look?